# How to add data from multiple models to same view (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to figure out how to have data from multiple models show up on the same calendar in my view. Right now it's showing birthdays, but i would love to add anniversaries & holidays as well (which are currently just lists in view).. *stripped unnecessary formatting for clarity

https://github.com/watu/table_builder

users/show.html.erb

```
 <% if @user.friends.any? %>
    <h3>Upcoming Birthdays</h3>
    <div id="calendar">
        <h2 id="month">
         <%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m") %>
         <%=h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
         <%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m") %>
        </h2>
                    <%= calendar_for @friends, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
                     <%= calendar.head('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun') %>
                      <%= calendar.day(:day_method => :dob) do |date, friends| %>
                       <%= date.day %>
                        <ul>
                            <% friends.each do |friend| %>
                            <li> <%= link_to h(friend.name), friends %><%= "\'s birthday"%></li>
                         <% end %>
                        </ul>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if @user.holidays.any? %>
    <h3>Upcoming Holidays</h3>
    <% @user.holidays.each do |hld| %>
      <td><%= hld.name %></td>
      <td><%= hld.date %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
  has_many :user_holidays
  has_many :holidays, :through => :user_holidays
  has_many :anniversaries



class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :date
  has_many :user_holidays
  has_many :users, :through => :user_holidays

end


class UserHoliday < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :holiday_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :holiday
end


class Anniversary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :anniversary_date, :spouse_name, :anniversaries, :interest_ids
  has_many :person_interests, :as => :person
  has_many :interests, :through => :person_interests
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing about a view that keeps it from using data from other models.  You just have to make sure that the controller action passes it to the view somehow.  You're currently passing one `@date` object and one `@user` object; if you want other objects you should set those as well.  I advise you to make those objects accessible via the `@user` object, which is to say that you should create instance methods for a User so that you can access them in a view

```
class User

  def birthdays
    ...
  end

  def anniversaries
    ...
  end

  def holidays
    ...
  end
end
```

And then in your view, you can simply call `@user.birthdays` etc, etc.

Comment: talking more in regards to this calendar setup... how would i incorporate the new code into my existing calendar? nothing i try seems to work

Comment: In other words this is a "calendar_for @friends" which is a separate model from User. Friends have birthdays as do users.. So how could i call user.birthdays within the framework of the @friends calendar?